# Window Azure SQL Server DB Backup to a local-Premise

Tags: sql-server, backup

One of my customers stopped subscribing to our services and they INSIST to have their data stored in their local SQL Server. Their data size is quite some amount though.

We did try to use the [Azure Sync](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/) (Preview) and the process is painful and troublesome.

Question came in mind, is there a traditional way that backup to .bak and restore to their SQL Server? Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Offtopic. Not really a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Answer (score 1):

I would ditch Azure Sync by all means .. buggy and still in preview since ages.

We have exactly same requirement and what I did was create SSIS package and load the data from Azure to OnPremise on a nightly basis. It works just fine once you set it up. Make sure to load the data as per FK relationship.

On other side, you can explore [Windows Azure SQL Database Import/Export Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2013/03/04/different-ways-to-backup-your-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx).

Comment: first of all, LOL on your first sentences, was felt that ways well, thanks for the solution, but in fact we dont required its run nightly basis, just one time work will do as they are not paid us anymore.

Comment: Then use azure migration assistant. It will work for you.